# How to assign #sth to string?

Tags: php, string, assign

I'd like to create a mechanism to substitute the URL link in `$menuitem['url']` for something like this - #link1, #link2, #link3. I've spend a couple hours with searching the way, but I'm still disappointed.

For example, I need to get this URL: http://chervo.ideatech.cz/Admin/#link1

instead of the current one: http://chervo.ideatech.cz/Admin/?pg=overview&table=data_obrazky

```
private function GetHtmlRecursive($arr) {
        $html = '';
        foreach ($arr AS $item) {
        ...
        ...
        ...
            else {
                $html .= '<li><a href="'.$item['url'].'">'.$item['nazev'].'</a></li>';
            }
        }

    return $html;
}



private function FillMenuItem(&$menuitem) {
    ...
    ...
    ...
    else {

        if (isset($menuitem['tab']))
            $this->FillByTabdef($menuitem);

        if ( (!isset($menuitem['url'])) && (isset($menuitem['tab'])) ) {
            $menuitem['url'] = '?pg=overview&amp;table='.$menuitem['tab'];
        }
        ...
        ...
        ...
    }
}
```

Is there any easy way, how to do that?

The whole code is here: http://codepad.org/DvwPJC1V

Comment: "for something like this" - please state precisely what you want

Comment: I just need to change the url, that starts with char "?" to url starting with character #.

Examples here:

http://chervo.ideatech.cz/Admin/?pg=overview&table=data_obrazky
to
http://chervo.ideatech.cz/Admin/#link1

Comment: where does `link1` come from?

Comment: "#link1" will just supply "?pg=overview&table=data_obrazky". It is not defined yet.

Answer (score 0):

```
$urls = array('http://chervo.ideatech.cz/Admin/?pg=overview&table=data_obrazky', 'http://chervo.ideatech.cz/Admin/?pg=pickles&table=food', 'http://chervo.ideatech.cz/Admin/?pg=auto&table=cars');

foreach($urls AS $url)
{
    //If http_build_url is available
    //$parse = parse_url($url);
    //unset($parse[PHP_URL_QUERY]);
    //$parse[PHP_URL_FRAGMENT] = "link1";
    //$newURL = http_build_url($parse);
    //var_dump($newURL);

    //otherwise do this

    $query = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);

    $newURL = str_replace("?" . $query, "#link1", $url);

    var_dump($newURL);
}
```

Try something like http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php to identify the parts of the URL you want to replace then either replace it with a simple string replace or if available http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-url.php

Alternatively you could simply delete everything after the `?` character then append `#link1`